# XML Parse for specific element in java

Tags: java, xml

Recently I tried to parse an XML File to do some testings on it.

I managed to read the XML File but I struggle to get to the element I want to read.

My XML File looks like this:

```
<Information1>
 <Information1> Lot of elements here
 <Info2>
  <Info3> 
<BlockElement1> 
     <sBlockElement1> sElement1 </sBlockElement1>
     <sBlockElement2> sElements2 </sBlockElement2>
     <sBlockElement2>  sElements2 </sBlockElement2> !it has the same name but different values than the one above
</BlockElement1>
<BlockElement1> 
     <sBlockElement1> sElement1 </sBlockElement1>
     <sBlockElement2> sElements2 </sBlockElement2>
     <sBlockElement2>  sElements2 </sBlockElement2> !it has the same name but different values than the one above
</BlockElement1>
<BlockElement1> 
     <sBlockElement1> sElement1 </sBlockElement1>
     <sBlockElement2> sElements2 </sBlockElement2>
     <sBlockElement2>  sElements2 </sBlockElement2> !it has the same name but different values than the one above
</BlockElement1>
</Info3></Info2></Information1></Information1>
```

I am trying to reach the BlockElement1 and Extract data from sBlockElement(i) where i=1,2

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Audiogramcurve aud=new Audiogramcurve();
        File fXmlFile = new File("C:\\Users\\UserNamer\\Desktop/My.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Info3");
            for(int i=0;i<nList.getLength();i++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(i);
                 System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

                        NodeList nListPoints = doc.getElementsByTagName("BlockElement1");

                         for(int tT=0;tT<nListPoints.getLength();tT++) {
                                Node nNodePoint = nListPoints.item(tT);
                                System.out.println(nNodePoint.getNodeName());
                                NodeList audMesList=doc.getElementsByTagName("sBlockElement1");
                                NodeList tonPointList=doc.getElementsByTagName("sBlockElement2");
                                //System.out.println(tonPointList.getLength());
                                for(int audI=0;audI<tonPointList.getLength();audI++) {
                                    Node nNodeAud = tonPointList.item(audI);
                                    System.out.println(nNodeAud.getNodeName());                                 
                                }


                     }
                 }


    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} `
```

The mistake is probably here :`NodeList nListPoints = doc.getElementsByTagName("BlockElement1");` but I can't find a way to take the next Element that is called BlockElement1 from a NodeList . (I know that this takes the elemnts from the beggining).

The problem is that it returns EVERY sBlockElement1 and not the specific one for the BlockElement1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there aren't any namespaces in your xml so you should consider using XPath as It is (as least for me) so much easy to use! [More info about XPath here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

Here is an example that I think can be helpful:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/Information1/Information1/Info2/Info3/BlockElement1/";

NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: its nice to use xpaths as long as you have no namespaces in xml.

Comment: You are wright but it seems that, in this case, he has not namespaces. Thanks for the point! I edit my answer!

Comment: I didnt say it is not the way to go - it was just a discaimer :) Using XPATH is still "easy" with namespaces, if you write some custom tweaks that are not supported out of the box nobody know why by JDK:P

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will try to use Xpath!

Comment: @MikeS. if you found helpful the answer, please check the green 'tick'! :)